postgresql crosstab weekday appointments for the week
I have a table with columns weekday, appointment, and appointment date for that week.
The table looks like this:



Weekday
Appointment
Date




Monday
Doctor
2022-04-01


Tuesday
Dentist
2022-04-02



And I would to display the table with Weekdays as columns:



Monday
Tuesday
...




Doctor
Dentist
...



So far my query looks like this:
select * from 
crosstab 
(
$$
select 
apt."name" as "Appointment"
, initcap(to_char(to_timestamp(apt."date"/1000), 'day')) as "Weekday"
from appointments as apt
where date_trunc('week', now()) <= to_timestamp(apt."date"/1000) 
and to_timestamp(apt."date"/1000) < date_trunc('week', now()) + '1 week'::interval 
$$,
$$
values ('Monday'::text), ('Tuesday'::text), ('Wednesday'::text), ('Thursday'::text), ('Friday'::text)
$$
)
as ct("Appointment" text, "Monday" text, "Tuesday"  text, "Wednesday" text, "Thursday"text, "Friday" text)


If you swap day for Day you don't need the initcap(). Adding some create table and insert statements to the question would make this reproducible and easier to inspect, fix and demonstrate.

Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.
